# Load image Previews

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, image-preloader

I'm currently working on a Jekyll-based Website, which contains quite a few high-resolution images.
I'm not very experienced in using javascript, but I wondered if it would be possible to create a javascript script to download any image on a website not from left top to right bottom, but every part of the image at the same time.
For example, if I had a giant 5MB 5K image, the browser would first display a low-resolution image, which's quality would increase until the complete image is loaded.
Is that possible? And if it is, is there already such a thing?
The image format does not matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called 'progressive image loading' in .jpg and can be set while saving an image for web in Photoshop.